# Problem changing cameras between scenes

Tags: animation, camera, scene

Just trying to make a simple intro animation, pretty much text only. I've never used Blender as anything but a video editor so I'm learning as I go.

My goal is to change cameras in different scenes. So the first scene has it's text and animation, and then the next scene with its own stuff. 
But I can't get the cameras to change during the animation. I've read about using Markers and binding each camera to a Marker. But it still won't change.

I feel I may have misunderstood what the scenes are for after reading the "Data System" section of the manual, as well as the "Linked Libraries".
If I did misunderstand something I'm not sure what the next step is to finish this small project.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say different scenes, are you talking about blender scenes in the list at the top? Markers switch cameras in the same scene, you use the VSE to merge different scenes into one animation.

Comment: So I did misunderstand what scenes were used for. 
Basically all I need to do is render out each animation and put them together in post? Or is there a way to do it pre-render?